# Where can I view WebSphere environment variables?

Tags: websphere

In WebSphere Application Server (version 6.1) my JDBC Provider Classpath is 
`${ORACLE_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/ojdbc14.jar`

Where in the WebSphere administration console can I see what the `ORACLE_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH` is set to?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to see it under **Environment > WebSphere Variables**:

[image: WAS vars]

Comment: Thanks for the useful graphic!